# Test multiple conditions to categorize and count

Tags: r

I'm new to R and coding in general.  I have a large dataset but here is a sample.  For each month of each year each case_number has to be categorized as either a CHILD or an ADULT and counted.  A case number can repeat in a month, but each case_number can only be counted once per month.  ad, cs, and em are vectors that include service codes.

Ultimate output I need to generate has the following columns: YEAR, MONTH, ADULT_COUNT, CHILD_COUNT.
Case_number will be counted in each month based on the following rules:

1. If cost center only in ad then ADULT.
2. If cost center only in cs then CHILD.
3. If cost center only in em then ADULT if age_at_service > 21, else CHILD
4. If cost center in ad and em then ADULT
5. If cost center in cs and em then CHILD
6. If cost center in cs and ad, see first instance in the month.  If it's in cs = CHILD,
   else ADULT

> ```
> # create sample dataset
> case_number <- c(1,1,1,1,2,2,3,4,4,4,5,5)
> age_at_service <- c(20,20,20,20,34,34,15,45,45,45,24,24)
> cost_center <- c(4000,4121,2000,2000,4000,121,2000,2121,4000,121,121,121)
> year <- c(2019, 2019, 2019, 2019, 2019, 2019, 2019, 2019, 2019, 2019, 2019, 2019)
> month <- c(1,1,1,1,2,1,1,1,1,1,2,2)
> date <- c('1/12/2019','1/11/2019','1/8/2019','1/1/2019','2/3/2019'
>           ,'1/7/2019','1/4/2019','1/23/2019','1/12/2019','1/3/2019','2/12/2019','2/14/2019')
> date <- as.Date(date,format = '%m/%d/%Y')
>
> tb <- tibble(case_number, age_at_service, cost_center, month, year, date)
> # service codes
> ad <- c(4000,4121)
> cs <- c(2000,2121)
> em <- (121)
> ```

In the above sample data, the results would be:

```
>  YEAR  MONTH  ADULT  CHILD    
>  2019    1      2      2
>  2019    2      2      0
```

I've created some more simplistic code, but am not sure where to start for this task.  Any direction is appreciated.

Comment: Can you check the 'ADULT' for "MONTH" 2

Comment: You are right - it should be two.  fixed it.

Comment: I have a doubt, which are the grouping columns i.e. does `case_number` also be used in grouping

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the condition is based on 'age_at_service, then we create the 'grp' column based on the age limit, get the `distinct` rows based on 'case_number', 'year', 'month', 'grp', `count` the frequency and reshape  too 'wide' format with `pivot_wider`

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
tb %>% 
   mutate(grp = case_when(age_at_service > 21 ~ "ADULT", TRUE ~ "CHILD")) %>%
   distinct(case_number, year, month, grp) %>%
   count(year, month, grp) %>% 
   pivot_wider(names_from = grp, values_from = n, values_fill = list(n = 0))
# A tibble: 2 x 4
#    year month ADULT CHILD
#  <dbl> <dbl> <int> <int>
#1  2019     1     2     2
#2  2019     2     2     0
```

---

Or if we consider to use the full list of conditions based on the vectors, 'ad', 'cs', 'em', place them in a `list`, convert to a two column tibble, then do a join with 'tb', `arrange` the rows based on 'year', 'month', 'case_number', 'date', after grouping by 'year', 'month', 'cost_center', create the 'grp' column based on the conditions and then do the same as in the above i.e. `distinct/count/pivot_wider`

```
library(purrr)
library(tibble)
lst(ad, cs, em) %>%
     enframe(value = "cost_center") %>% 
     unnest(c(cost_center)) %>% 
     right_join(tb) %>%
     arrange(year, month, case_number, date) %>% 
     group_by(year, month, case_number) %>% 
     mutate(grp = case_when(n_distinct(name) == 1 && name == 'ad'
           ~ 'ADULT', 
       n_distinct(name) == 1 && name == 'cs' ~ 'CHILD',
       n_distinct(name) == 1 && name  == 'em' & age_at_service > 21 ~ 'ADULT',
        all(c('ad', 'em') %in% name) ~ 'ADULT',
        all(c('cs', 'em') %in% name) ~ 'CHILD',
        all(c('cs', 'ad') %in% name) && first(name)=='cs' ~ 'CHILD',
        all(c('cs', 'ad') %in% name) && first(name) != 'cs' ~ 'ADULT',
        TRUE ~ NA_character_)) %>% 
        ungroup %>% 
        distinct(case_number, year, month, grp) %>%
        count(year, month, grp) %>% 
        pivot_wider(names_from = grp, values_from = n, values_fill = list(n = 0))
# A tibble: 2 x 4
#   year month ADULT CHILD
#  <dbl> <dbl> <int> <int>
#1  2019     1     2     2
#2  2019     2     2     0
```

Comment: Thank you.  This is so much simpler than I expected.  I've been using pipes and tidyverse, but have a lot more to learn.  Much appreciated.

Comment: @mr_puddles  It could be either because I useed the wrong  grouping variables or some of the conditions mentioned in your post have to be changed?

Comment: @mr_puddles The reason   I mentioned is you know better about the conditions than me

Comment: Hi @akrun the first short code does not look at all the conditions, but only considers age_at_service.  It does get the right results, but by coincidence.  The longer code, where you take all the conditions into account, does not yield the correct results.

Comment: @mr_puddles If you check the conditiions, these are the same you provided

Comment: @mr_puddles ok go t it, it is grouping by `case_number` i put the wrong one

Comment: @mr_puddles  can you check now.  It is getting the correct output now